# Application_End fires after Application_Start in global.asax when restarting

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

We've noticed that Application_End for the old app domain can sometimes fire long after Application_Start for the new app domain when restarting a website.. We've seen delays of up to 45 seconds plus..

I'm guessing ASP.NET prioritizes the compilation and starting of the new app domain before unloading the old app domain..?

I found this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.100).aspx

But I can't really find any info about the delay between the old and new app domains.. Can anyone shed some light on this..?

Is it configurable..?

Comment: How are you restarting? IISReset, app pool recycle, code deployment? This is probably more to do with how IIS works, rather than the asp.net lifecycle works.

Comment: We're seeing this currently with code re-compilations. I haven't checked for all the other restart events..

Answer (score 4):

I did not found anything to configure the delay, but there is an option to disallow the new worker process to start before the old one exits.

In the IIS Manger go to "Application Pool", select the Application Pool your application is part of. Select "Advanced Settings" in the context menu. Set the option "Disable Overlapped Recycle" to "TRUE".